# Split string with defined and undefined character

Tags: python

I have a text file which looks like

```
text='\n> lefortoff\n> donna_marta\n> agizatullina\n> shshifter\n< bagira\n< recoder'
```

and I would like to split it by every `\n` but also skipping `>` and `<` and spaces after them.

I'm doing it via this code

```
names = text.split('\n> ')
last_names = names[-1].split('\n< ')
names = names[1:-1]
names.extend(last_names)
```

but wonder if there is simpler way of doing this with pseudocode like:

```
text.split('\n%s1%s2', %s1 = undefined, %s2 = undefined)
```

so those s1 can be `>`, `<` and s2 would be space  .

Comment: You can use a regular expression.

Comment: See [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split)

Comment: If you need to learn regular expressions, read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use the regex:  `\n[<>]\s` as follows:

`[<>]` is just like your `s1`, and `\s` is your s2.

**Explanation**:

`\n` to match `\n`

`[<>]`  character class to match either `<` or `>`

`\s`  to match also the trailing space so that the extracted strings have no extra spaces

```
import re
re.split(r'\n[<>]\s', text)


#output

['',
 'lefortoff',
 'donna_marta',
 'agizatullina',
 'shshifter',
 'bagira',
 'recoder']
```

Answer (score 0):

@SeaBean's answer is the most general and would be my first choice. But if you really only have two expressions to split on, you could use a nested loop with `str.split()`, like this:

```
text='\n> lefortoff\n> donna_marta\n> agizatullina\n> shshifter\n< bagira\n< recoder'
last_names = [
    n
    for part in text.split('\n> ')
    for n in part.split('\n< ')
]
print(last_names)
# ['', 'lefortoff', 'donna_marta', 'agizatullina', 'shshifter', 'bagira', 'recoder']
```

This uses the fact that if you split on one of the delimiters, the resulting parts will sometimes be lists of names with the other delimiter between them. So we split first on one delimiter, then take each part and split on the other delimiter (if needed).

This creates a nested list structure, but if we just report everything we get in the inner loop, it produces a flat list.